# My ERC-721 minting gas fee is almost $10000. Too high. How fix it?

Tags: solidity, metamask, gas, gas-price, gas-limit

[image]

I just deployed NFT Dapp on **mainnet**.

Estimated gas fee is too High. It's almost $10000

How can i fix it?

I never knew on local canache or  rinkeby testnet

There was fine gas fee..

is it depend on truffle-config.js gas price?

I learn that based on complex of .sol code...

I use **@openzapplin ERC-721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable**

and solc ^0.8.11

Here is my react web3 javascript for minting

```
await token.methods.createToken(uri, amount).send({from: account, value: tokens(_value)})
.on('receipt', (receipt) => {
    setBuyDisable(false)
    window.alert('Praying Bear successfully minted!')
    console.log("resultado =", receipt)
})
.on('error', (error, receipt) => {
  setBuyDisable(false)
  console.log('Participate Error - Receipt', error, receipt)
  console.log('Error - Message', error.message)
  checkErrorMessage(error.message)
})
```

And my token.sol minttoken function is here

```
function createToken (string memory _uri, uint256 _amount) public payable returns (uint) {
    require(totalSupply() < maxSupply - (_amount - 1), "Sorry, it just sold out");
    uint256 currentprice = _amount == 1 ? soloPrice : _amount == 4 ? quatroPrice : tenPrice;
    require(msg.value == currentprice, "Price must be equal to listing price");
    payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
    uint newItemId = 0;
    for (uint i=0; i<_amount; i++) {
        newItemId = minttoken(_uri); 
    }
    return newItemId;
}
function minttoken (string memory _uri) private returns (uint) {
    uint256 newItemId = totalSupply() + 1;
    _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _uri = "ipfs://<HARDCODEDMYIPFSTOKEN>";
    _uri = string(abi.encodePacked(_uri,"/",Strings.toString(newItemId),".json"));
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, _uri);
    return newItemId;
}
```

++ To fix this am I **truffle migrate --reset**   do?

Comment: I encountered a very similar problem. In my case, I was referring to a contract from a testnet and that got deployed to mainnet. The gas estimations were obviously fine on test but started to fail on mainnet making Metamask show enormous values (5ETH+). Please see my thread [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119977/erc721-contract-deployed-to-mainnet-gives-enormous-minting-fees/).

Answer (score 0):

It is something normal to have such a high gas fee for deployment. I would suggest moving your contract to a L2 like polygon or arbitrum for cheaper deployment.